# Table row background-color transition not working

Tags: css, css-transitions

Given this HTML:

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr class='not-latest'><td>Test</td></tr>    
    <tr class='latest'><td>Test</td></tr>    
    <tr class='not-latest'><td>Test</td></tr>    
    <tr class='not-latest'><td>Test</td></tr>    
    <tr class='not-latest'><td>Test</td></tr>    
    <tr class='not-latest'><td>Test</td></tr>    
    <tr class='not-latest'><td>Test</td></tr>    
</table>
```

And this CSS:

```
tr{
    background-color: #ccc;
}
tr.not-latest{
    background-color: #fff;
}
tr.latest{
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: background-color 4s;
    transition-delay: 2s;    
}
```

I would *expect* the row with the class `latest` to start with a background-color of `#ccc`, delay for 2 seconds and then slowly fade to `#fff` over 4 seconds.

However, this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6e2uao7v/5/ - would suggest otherwise. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: How this transition will be triggered? As far as I know, If you want to achieve this only with CSS, you need to trigger it, like "hover". So your fiddle would be http://jsfiddle.net/tallrye/6e2uao7v/8/

Comment: Ok, so it is my misunderstanding. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the transition on the first css rule applied to the element, like

```
tr{
    background-color: #ccc;
    transition: background-color 1s;
}

tr:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

This example css will show the transition when you hover the row with the mouse.